# VueJs Wall with real time change

Tags: vue.js

I have JSON with data.
If JSON is updating I need to update data on my page in real-time.

```
new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                data: {
                  posts: 'Hello',
                  results: ''
                },
                mounted() {

                    axios.get(url).then(response => {
                      this.results = response.data
                    })
                  axios.get(apiURL).then(response => (this.posts = response.data));
                }
              });
```

Comment: What does 'JSON is updating' mean? Client app needs to know somehow that data was updated on server side? Two popular options are Websockets and HTTP long polling. They aren't specific to Vue. Proceed from this.

Comment: You can also periodically pull the data every minute or so with `setTimeout`.

Comment: Tell us how best to do this

Comment: You will probably need a socket to detect incoming changes if the server initiates sending a new version of your JSON (Making some assumptions here). Then you'll need a backend that is able to maintain a socket connection (like nodejs or https://www.websocket.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I will recommend you to check `Socket.io`, it will give you the possibility to push data from server to your front-end  `Vue app` at a specific event.
Check this article for more: https://medium.com/js-dojo/build-a-real-time-chat-app-with-vuejs-socket-io-and-nodejs-714c8eefa54e